# Ruby open-uri proxy authentication fails

Tags: ruby, http, proxy, open-uri

I'm coding a native Ruby script to scrap a website using Nokogiri, whenever I pass proxy options to the open-uri `open()` method, it returns `407 Proxy Authentication Required` but my options does have the authentification details, here's my code

```
proxy_url = URI.parse("http://12.34.567.89:PORT")
session = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://google.com", :proxy_http_basic_authentication =>[proxy_url, "username", "password"]
```

Note: As my proxy is premium, I have replaced real proxy credentials with fake one

Answer (score 0):

I have a restrictive proxy at work but the followig works.
Try the code with your proxy credentials.
I used Nokogiri here for parsing but you don't realy need it for getting the HTML.

```
require 'net/http' 
require 'uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818853/ruby-open-uri-proxy-authentication-fails'

proxy_host, proxy_port, proxy_user, proxy_pass = '****', 8080, "*****", "*****" 
uri = URI.parse(url)

Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy_host, proxy_port, proxy_user, proxy_pass).start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  http.get(uri.path) do |str|
    puts Nokogiri::HTML(str).text
  end
end
```

Comment: No, it throws HTTPProxyAuthenticationRequired error (Cache access denied) , I tried my proxy with same credentials using Curl it works perfectly, but through ruby it isn't.