# OpenURI::HTTPError: 401 Unauthorized with open-uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, open-uri

I am trying to Hit my own server url with open() command but its says

> OpenURI::HTTPError: 401 Unauthorized
>
> from /.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:358:in `open_http'

My domain name is let say http://example.com and i am trying to hit the url with open command that is

```
open("http://example.com/system/contract/abc")
```

But it gave the above error. On my localhost its working fine. Suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: Obviously, `http://example.com/system/contract/abc` requires authorization :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the URL you're trying to access requires authentication.
There are couple of example / answers to authentication questions using OpenURI in stackoverflow. Here are some of them:

[OpenUri causing 401 Unauthorized error with HTTPS URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763399/openuri-causing-401-unauthorized-error-with-https-url)

and if you are using a proxy:
[Ruby open-uri proxy authentication fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818853/ruby-open-uri-proxy-authentication-fails)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the direction. Yes we are using basic authentication on our server so i needed to provide it to perform that action. (y)